# How to pass custom class as parameter in thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, network-programming

I am writing a server in C++ and need to pass the Connection class to a thread so that the thread can do the handling. But when I try, it gives this error.

```
Connection.cpp:12:15: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::thread'
  std::thread newThread(threadFunc,this);
              ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:340:9: note: 
      candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f',
      but 2 arguments were provided
thread::thread(_Fp __f)
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:220:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    thread(const thread&);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:227:5: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were
      provided
    thread() _NOEXCEPT : __t_(_LIBCPP_NULL_THREAD) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I have tried looking it up but it keeps saying just to use `std::thread(func,parameter)` but it dosen't work, as you can see here.

Here is my source:

Connection.cpp

```
#include "Connection.h"

void threadFunc(Connection c) {

}

Connection::Connection(sockaddr_in addr,uint32_t addrLen, uint32_t fd) {
  socketAddr = addr;
  socketAddrLength = addrLen;
  socketFD = fd;
  char buffer[2048] = {0};
  std::thread newThread(threadFunc,this);
  while(true) {
    if (recv(socketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0 ) > 0) {
      ConnectionDefinition def(socketAddr);
      printf("%s says: %s", def.toString().c_str(),buffer);
    }
    bzero(buffer,sizeof(char)*2048);
  }
}

Connection::~Connection() {
  close(socketFD);
  printf("Server closed connection to client\n");
}
```

Connection.h

```
#pragma once

#include "include.h"

class Connection {
private:
  sockaddr_in socketAddr;
  uint32_t socketAddrLength;
  uint32_t socketFD;
public:
  Connection(sockaddr_in addr,uint32_t addrLen, uint32_t fd);
  ~Connection();
};
```

I have included  in include.h so that's not the issue

include.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

#include "utils.h"

#include "Connection.h"
```

Comment: `threadFunc` takes a `Connection` not a `Connection*` as parameter. You also cannot call `threadFunc(this)` for the same reason, though the error would be less obscure ;)

Comment: can you show how to fix this? do I have to use &this or &connection?

Comment: It's just `void threadFunc(Connection* c)`. But you could also consider a proper member `Connection::threadFunc( )`.

Comment: how do proper members work with multithreading tho

Answer (score 0):

#### The type mismatch

This is because `this` is a pointer of type `Connection*` and you are trying to pass it to a function accepting a copy of `Connection`. It looks like your intent is actually to pass a *pointer* to `threadFunc`, which would look like this:

```
void threadFunc(Connection* c) { ... }
```

Now you can pass `this` to the variadic constructor of `std::thread` and it should work correctly.

*If it still does not work*, you can try the following option:

#### The variadic constructor of `std::thread`

From my personal experience the variadic constructor of `std::thread` is a little finicky and does not give good errors, so it might be simpler just to use a lambda to bind your argument when you're creating your thread:

```
std::thread newThread([this] { threadFunc(this); });
```

This will likely get inlined by the compiler and create no performance penalty either.

Comment: the first method still complained about there being no viable constructor. The second one then gave this error. ```Connection.cpp:13:25: error: expected expression
  std::thread newThread([this] { threadFunc(this); });
                        ^
1 error generated.```

Comment: I agree about std::thread with more than 1 parameter can finicky and annoying sometimes (most of the time)